# Prestashop 1.6xx Export all the orders with discounted products and discount code from database

Tags: sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

i need to export in a CSV file, all the orders with a discount code and discounted products.

I've done this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_orders` WHERE `date_add` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 
00:00:00' and '2017-03-31 23:59:59' AND `total_discounts` > 0 AND 
`current_state` LIKE 4
```

and now i have a list of orders with a discount code, but i need also the orders with discounted products.

How can i do?
Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Left Join with order details:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ps_orders` o 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_detail` od
      ON o.`id_order` = od.`id_order`
WHERE o.`date_add` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-03-31 23:59:59' 
      AND (o.`total_discounts` > 0 OR od.`reduction_percent` > 0 OR od.`reduction_amount` > 0)
      AND o.`current_state` LIKE 4
```

If you want, you can choose the fields you want, instead of the *.
If you only need the data from orders, use:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM `ps_orders` o 
LEFT JOIN `ps_order_detail` od
      ON o.`id_order` = od.`id_order`
WHERE o.`date_add` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-03-31 23:59:59' 
      AND (o.`total_discounts` > 0 OR od.`reduction_percent` > 0 OR od.`reduction_amount` > 0)
      AND o.`current_state` LIKE 4
GROUP BY o.`id_order`
```

Comment: I've made some little changes but works perfectly! Thank You!